# elixir: defining type specification for maps/hashdicts

Tags: generics, types, static-analysis, elixir

In statically typed languages with generics, like C#, I can specify in the method signature that each of the map's keys is an atom and each value is a list of {string, int} tuple. How do I define the type specification for function arguments like that in Elixir?

PS: if you are reading this and have >1500 rating, could you please create a type-specification tag.

Comment: I'm not familiar with elixir, but it claims to be a "dynamic language", which usually means that it does not have a formal type system.  So... use a comment?

Comment: it has type specifications, which can be used by the static analysis tool Dialyzer - http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/Kernel.Typespec.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would define it like so:

```
@type bar :: %{atom => [{binary, integer}]}

@spec foo(bar) :: bar
def foo(bar), do: bar
```

The above defines a new type, which is your map of atom keys to lists of binary/integer tuples, and then uses that type in the type spec for `foo`.

Comment: just to be sure, I have to specify it as a type beforehand, I can't just inline it? If so, should I keep all my custom types in a separate module and just import them, to avoid copy-pasting the type definition in multiple modules?

Comment: You can definitely inline it, but I find it hard to read if you have multiple complex types all inlined. It's also a little more explicit about *what* the type is, rather than just the structure of it. You can define types in other modules and use them via `Module.type_name`.

Comment: great, thanks! In this sense, Elixir's static analysis is more granular than Go's since Go doesn't let you define functions that take your custom types as arguments. (Disregard if you haven't used Go)

Comment: I should clarify that `bar` in `def foo(bar)` doesn't actually refer to the type, but rather reflects the naming of a variable which matches the type of value you expect `foo` to receive. You could call that function with `foo(5)` and it would compile just fine. It's only when you run dialyzer that you'll get the errors letting you know that you are passing the wrong type to `foo`. That said, it does provide a much greater degree of information during static analysis, which can be very useful.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - Elixir's static analysis supports custom types while Go doesn't. Though, its static analysis is much more limited than Go's static typing, since it can only check function signatures but nothing inside the method itself.

Comment: Dialyzer does check elements of your code within a function, including calls to other functions with type specs. It's not limited just to function signatures.

Comment: wow! It seems like it's pretty much at par with static typing. Are there any scenarios where it can't catch something that a type system (Go or C#) would?

Comment: Assuming your application consistently uses type specifications everywhere, it should catch all the same errors that Go or C# would. The issue is that type specs aren't enforced, so you can still write code that is invalid. Static type systems won't even let you compile your code if the type contracts are broken. There might be some scenarios that a static type system (like Go's or C#'s, not like Haskell's) would catch which Dialyzer won't, but those are probably few and far between.

Answer (score 1):

For inline spec it goes like this:

```
defmodule LousyCalculator do
  @spec add(number, number) :: {number, String.t}
  def add(x, y), do: {x + y, "You need a calculator to do that?!"}

  @spec multiply(number, number) :: {number, String.t}
  def multiply(x, y), do: {x * y, "Jeez, come on!"}
end
```

If you expect a structure then the type is:

```
@spec struct_returner_and_getter(%Struct_name1{}) :: %Struct_name2{}
```

Source: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html